# Error "A non-numeric value encountered " - I tried to change the PHP version, but it's still showing the error

Tags: php, error-handling, server

This is the error which is receive:

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /Pagination.php on line 42
>   Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /Pagination.php on line 43

The below lines are 41,42,43

```
{
    $this->total    = isset($params['total']) ? $params['total'] + 1 : osc_search_total_pages() + 1;
    $this->selected = isset($params['selected'])
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: `$params['total']` is probably a string. What does `var_dump($params['total'])` give back?

Comment: `$params['total']` is non numeric, thats about all one can say

Comment: `intval( $params['total'] ) + 1`??

Comment: Caution with that @RamRaider you'll destroy floats.

Comment: @user3783243 - true story! swap `intval` for `floatval`

Comment: If it is non numeric then why error is coming you can see on my home page localads.pk the bottom of page

Comment: We can't tell if you if it is/isn't numeric. Use the function provided earlier to see what you actually have. (Based on the error returned though it is not numeric)

Comment: @user3783243 its not working i try all the above options.

Comment: You haven't told us anything. What does `var_dump($params['total'])` return?

Comment: @user3783243 it is coming null .

Comment: Okay, then what does `osc_search_total_pages()` return to you? I guess you're going into that case.

Comment: I just fix the issue by add the ini_set('display_errors', 0); in not the same file add this in config.php file . I found this solution on some other website.